# Easier flow control in Python

Tags: python, flags, flow-control

In the following code I'm trying to check if the variable "new_shape" already exists within "shape_list". If it does not exist already, I want to add it; if it does exist, I just want to leave it. So far, I have only achieved this using flags. I'm sure there's a way to accomplish the same thing more efficiently without flags. Any suggestions? 
Thanks for any help you give!

```
    flag = 0
    for shape in shape_list:
        if new_shape == shape:
            flag = 1
            break
    if flag == 0:
        shape_list.append(new_shape)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
if new_shape not in shape_list:
    shape_list.append(new_shape)
```

Comment: Wow thanks! Still learning the ropes in Python, thanks a bunch!

Comment: If order is not important you may also want to use a set instead of a list.

Comment: @whodareswins Using a `set` is a great idea, if possible (@Wichert is right). The existence check is (an extremely low constant) O(1), as opposed to a `list`, where the existence check is O(N).

Comment: Thanks! I previously thought only dicts had a O(1) existence check.

Comment: Even if you need order, you can still maintain a `set()` as well as a list and use it for uniqueness checking.

Answer (score 2):

And for an answer that preserves the original flow (although is usually less efficient than the other answer):

```
for shape in shape_list:
    if new_shape == shape:
        break
else:
    shape_list.append(new_shape)
```

Comment: I didn't know you can change indentation like you did to change flow. Thanks!

Comment: @whodareswins: It's not "changing flow" per se. In Python, `if`, `for`, `while`, and `try` all support an `else` clause; for the loops, it executes if the loop is not broken out of.

Comment: Very useful. Is this uniquely "pythonic" or also in other languages too?

Comment: @whodareswins: I haven't seen it in any other languages I've come across, but that only means that it's rare, not necessarily unique.

Answer (score 0):

If order is not import, you might be able to use a `set` ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)).